# TableStorage.ReplaceUpdateEntity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

There is a method `ReplaceUpdateEntity` for the object of `TableStorage` which is used in `AzureStorage` section. I tried googling of what it might do or to get an example. Any brief description or a link pointing towards this is welcome.

```
TableStorageTestEntity tableStorageTestEntity = new TableStorageTestEntity()
        {
            TableId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            TablePurpose = "UpdateEntity"                
        };

        string partitionKey = "31072015";
        string rowKey = "0108201551";
        bool result = this.tableStorage.ReplaceUpdateEntity(this.TableName, partitionKey, rowKey, tableStorageTestEntity);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

Actually I am running this test and the test fails. So I would like to understand about this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`InsertOrReplace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertorreplace.aspx). This operation will create an entity if it does not exist otherwise it will update the entity by replacing all of its attributes with the new values. Here's the sample code:

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Address");
        var entity = new DynamicTableEntity("pk", "rk");
        entity.Properties.Add("Attribute1", new EntityProperty("Attribute 1 Value"));
        TableOperation upsertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
        table.Execute(upsertOperation);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about 'InsertOrReplace' but the method that I am looking for is 'ReplaceUpdateEntity' which is a method of the object of 'TableStorage' . Azure SDK2.5 is the version

Comment: Can you share the link to this method or link from where you are using this code?

Comment: The issue is that I am not getting any link to this method or any link about it. We recently Upgraded to Azure SDK 2.5 and we are running test methods as a part of that. This was a method in it.

Comment: What SDK version you were using before upgrading to 2.5?

Comment: We were using Azure SDK 2.4

Comment: I don't think much has changed as far as storage client library is concerned between 2.4 and 2.5. Is it possible that you are using an older version of storage client library? Also, is it possible that you wrote your own library and implemented tableStorage.ReplaceUpdateEntity. AFAIK, I have never seen this function in Microsoft's storage client library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85056/discussion-between-ajay-and-gaurav-mantri).